# Windows 7: does formatting a disk actually write zeros to it?

Tags: windows-7, formatting, overwrite

According to [this article from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/941961), zeros are written to an entire disk when it is formatted (not using the quick format option) in Windows Vista and newer versions of Windows. My question is the following:

Does this also apply to Windows 7? The above article from Microsoft does not specify Windows 7 under "Applies to", although Windows 7 is (to the best of my knowledge) a later version?

Comment: Updated my answer with proof of this being the case.

Comment: This is not just to verify read/write, some people might have argued that this is what they expected was to occur - protection against data recovery was expected. Zeroing flash memory makes later recovery of lost data a lot easier as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes, in the case of versions of Windows after Vista.

Prior to Windows Vista, a full format was the same as a quick format, but included a disk scan for bad sectors. As of Vista, this scan was replaced by [writing zeroes to each sector of the drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/941961/change-in-the-behavior-of-the-format-command-in-windows-vista-and-late) (which in turn would reveal any bad sectors that couldn't be written to).

Another source [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/formatting-disks-and-drives-frequently-asked-questions#) related definitively to Windows 7 states:

> ## What's a quick format?
>
> **Quick format** is a formatting option that creates a new file table on a
> hard disk but **does not fully overwrite or erase the disk**. A quick
> format is much faster than **a normal format, which fully erases any**
> **existing data on the hard disk.**

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

I don't know why the source you've provided *isn't* mentioning Windows 7, but it does apply.

### Evidence

#### Prior to formatting my SD card:

[image]

Full format complete:

[image]

#### After formatting my SD card:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could anyone confirm that it actually works in practice? I.e. that a disk is in fact overwritten with zeros when it's formatted in Windows 7?

Comment: To zero the drive using format requires it be done from the command line...https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/941961

Comment: @Moab I'm not sure the source means only for the command line. It even says that the `Windows Explorer: Click to select the Perform a quick format check box.` is the same command as `Command line: Use the format /q command.` - implying they operate in the same way. Have posted evidence that the GUI *does* zero the drive.

Comment: @user49897 Proof added using HxD to view the drive contents.