# Secure data wipe before laptop sell

Tags: ssd, security, file-management, secure-erase

I have two SSDs in my laptop (dell xps 15 9550):

1. Toshiba 256gb (PCIe) `THNSN5256GPU7`
2. Samsung 1tb (sata 3) `EVO860`

Both are fully encrypted with VeraCrypt.

Is it safe, to simply make a quick-format on both disks and install windows on one of them ? or maybe I do have to do an extra operation like f.e. "removing vera crypt keys" first ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Erase disk before selling](https://superuser.com/questions/1370584/erase-disk-before-selling) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/securely-erasing-all-data-from-a-hard-drive)

Comment: This question is also a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/101465/how-can-i-securely-format-a-solid-state-drive) question

Comment: Most of those dupes are out of date. If a drive is fully encrypted always & has been , then a simple erase will wipe the data & the encryption keys far beyond any hope of recovery. [Whatever you do, don't follow the advice in the deleted answer below, if you can see it. Unencrypt first & you just gave all your data away. Format from encrypted.]

Comment: sorry, confusing typo…  'always & has been' ==  '& always has been'

Answer (score 1):

First of all, most of the suggested answers are out-of-date, just like @tetsujin said.

Having said that, I will answer my question for future readers.

1. **If you use windows with `bitlocker` and your computer has `TPM`**:

   1. All that should be necessary is to encrypt the drive and wipe TPM (`ctrl`+`r` -> `tpm.msc` -> `Clear TPM`). `TPM` is a chip on the motherboard that bitlocker uses to store encryption keys.
   2. [If you're really paranoid, after clearing the TPM you could boot a Ubuntu live CD and use hdparm to do an ATA secure erase on the SSD.](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/4o1nn8/secure_erase_a_toshiba_ssd_in_an_xps_15/d48ruy9/)
   3. [Instead of hdparm, you can just run `blkdiscard /dev/sda` - that'll TRIM the whole drive (so don't ever try that on an SSD that has data you care about).](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/4o1nn8/secure_erase_a_toshiba_ssd_in_an_xps_15/d48ruy9/)
2. **If you use VeraCrypt**

   1. Encrypt the entire drive
   2. Wipe the disk (just like suggested by @tetsujin) using f.e. `diskpart` or by doing what was said in `1.2` or `1.3`

**Note1**: [VeraCrypt does not use `TPM`](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/FAQ.html), so no need to clean it, in the `2` case 
**Note2**: Sometimes SSD manufacturers release tools/utilities that allow to do
"Secure Erase", you might use it to wipe your disk if this is the case for you